# Retain R dataframe index values when converting to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, r, rpy2, lme4

Fitted mixed effects model using R (base version 3.5.2) package LME4, run via rpy2 2.9.4 from Python 3.6

Able to print random effects as an indexed dataframe, where the index values are the values of the categorical variable(s) used to define the groups (using  [radon data](https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/GLM-hierarchical.html)):

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri, default_converter
from rpy2.robjects.conversion import localconverter
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

lme4 = importr('lme4')

mod = lme4.lmer(**kwargs) # Omitting arguments for brevity
r_ranef = ro.r['ranef']
re = r_ranef(mod)
print(re[1])
                           Uppm   (Intercept)         floor   (Intercept)
AITKIN            -0.0026783361 -2.588735e-03  1.742426e-09 -0.0052003670
ANOKA             -0.0056688495 -6.418760e-03 -4.482764e-09 -0.0128942943
BECKER             0.0021906431  1.190746e-03  1.211201e-09  0.0023920238
BELTRAMI           0.0093246041  8.190172e-03  5.135196e-09  0.0164527872
BENTON             0.0018747838  1.049496e-03  1.746748e-09  0.0021082742
BIG STONE         -0.0073756824 -2.430404e-03  0.000000e+00 -0.0048823057
BLUE EARTH         0.0112939204  4.176931e-03  5.507525e-09  0.0083908075
BROWN              0.0069223055  2.544912e-03  4.911563e-11  0.0051123339
```

Converting this to a pandas DataFrame, the categorical values are lost from the index and replaced by integers:

```
pandas2ri.ri2py_dataframe(r_ranef[1])  # r_ranef is a dict of dataframes

    Uppm  (Intercept)         floor  (Intercept)
0  -0.002678    -0.002589  1.742426e-09    -0.005200
1  -0.005669    -0.006419 -4.482764e-09    -0.012894
2   0.002191     0.001191  1.211201e-09     0.002392
3   0.009325     0.008190  5.135196e-09     0.016453
4   0.001875     0.001049  1.746748e-09     0.002108
5  -0.007376    -0.002430  0.000000e+00    -0.004882
6   0.011294     0.004177  5.507525e-09     0.008391
7   0.006922     0.002545  4.911563e-11     0.005112
```

How do I retain the values of the original index?

The [doc](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lme4/versions/1.1-19/topics/ranef) suggests `as.data.frame` could contain `grp`, which might be the values I'm after, but I'm struggling to implement that through rpy2; e.g.,

```
r_ranef = ro.r['ranef.as.data.frame']
```

does not work

Comment: Isolated problem to `pandas2ri.ri2py_dataframe`, which is discarding the index of the R dataframe

Comment: What is your version of `rpy2`: `print(rpy2.__version__)` or `pip show rpy2`? As of [2.7.3](https://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/changes.html#release-2-7-3), the R data frame *row.names* propagates as *index* in pandas data frame using `pandas2ri.ri2py_dataframe`.

Comment: Edit: added rpy2 version 2.9.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider adding `row.names` as a new column in R data frame and then use this column to `set_index` in Pandas data frame:

```
base = importr('base')

# ADD NEW COLUMN TO R DATA FRAME
re[1] = base.transform(re[1], index = base.row_names(re[1]))

# SET INDEX IN PANDAS DATA FRAME
py_df = (pandas2ri.ri2py_dataframe(re[1])
                     .set_index('index')
                     .rename_axis(None)
        )
```

And to do so across all data frames in list, use R's `lapply` loop and then Python's list comprehension for new list of Pandas indexed data frames.

```
base = importr('base')

mod = lme4.lmer(**kwargs)          # Omitting arguments for brevity
r_ranef = lme4.ranef(mod)

# R LAPPLY
new_r_ranef = base.lapply(r_ranef, lambda df: 
                          base.transform(df, index=base.row_names(df)))

# PYTHON LIST COMPREHENSION
py_df_list = [(pandas2ri.ri2py_dataframe(df)
                         .set_index('index')
                         .rename_axis(None)
              ) for df in new_r_ranef]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri, default_converter
from rpy2.robjects.conversion import localconverter

r_dataf = ro.r("""
data.frame(
  Uppm = rnorm(5),
  row.names = letters[1:5]
)
""")

with localconverter(default_converter + pandas2ri.converter) as conv:
    pd_dataf = conv.rpy2py(r_dataf)

# row names are "a".."f"
print(r_dataf)

# row names / indexes are now 0..4
print(pd_dataf)
```

This is likely a minor bug/missing feature in rpy2, but the workaround is rather straightforward:

```
with localconverter(default_converter + pandas2ri.converter) as conv:
    pd_dataf = conv.rpy2py(r_dataf)
pd_dataf.index = r_dataf.rownames
```

Comment: Per listed [bug fix](https://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/changes.html#release-2-7-3) in comment, why did the original conversion not work to migrate *row.names* using `pandas2ri.ri2py_dataframe`?

Comment: Likely a regression... and there was no unit test to catch it. This is now followed up at https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/484/losing-info-when-converting-to-pandas .

Comment: And this is now fixed (possibly again) with a companion unit test:  https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/commits/0ab099c1c8f98fa17f74aaaa954fe82c5d370945

Comment: To take advantage of the fix, I need rpy2 3.0.0?  How would I do that (`pip install rpy2 --upgrade` takes me as far as 2.9.5, which clearly didn't include the fix)

Comment: Yes. And rpy2-3.0.0 is not yet released. Installing the dev version is straighforward though. See for example https://colab.research.google.com/gist/rpy2-lgautier-build/eeeb0844ada42b24c3e85f3b743b9157/rpy2.ipynb

Comment: Thank you @lgautier. I must have something else wrong on my end that's preventing LME4 from importing with rpy2 3.0.0dev -- `lme4 = importr('lme4')` gives me `ValueError: <rpy2.rinterface.ExprSexpVector object at 0x7f4680e4ebc8> [RTYPES.EXPRSXP] is not an R vector` whereas before, this import was working. Still able to `importr('base')` and `importr('stats`) with rpy2 3.0.0dev. I uninstalled rpy2 2.9.5 before installing 3.0.0dev per the colab link above, refreshing my IDE (Pycharm) afterward.

Comment: This was bug, which should now be fixed. Try again (after installing latest snapshot for rpy2-dev).